# Posix Serial Connection with Callbacks

Tags: linux, macos, serial-port, posix

I am trying to communicate with an arduino using the code from,

http://todbot.com/blog/2006/12/06/arduino-serial-c-code-to-talk-to-arduino/

which uses termios to open and talk to an arduino in a non blocking way which works fine. What I was wondering is when on Java using rxtx I can register a callback function that is called when ever there is data on the line so that I don't have to manually check. I googled but could not find any info on how to register a callback function?

I am on Linux/OS X and I am trying to avoid launching a new thread just to watch/read data on the line.

Answer (score 1):

Posix itself does not define a way to assign a callback function to be called when serial data arrives. The standard way to do this type of processing if you don't want to use a seperate thread is to use the `select` library function. This allows you program to define a set of file descriptors your program is interested in and then go to sleep. Select will automatically wake up your process if something interesting happens to one of the file descriptors you've declared interest in (such as new data becoming available for reading). This avoids having to busy-wait and poll multiple descriptors for activity.

Another option would be to use a library like libevent which sits on top of the Posix layer and provides the callback infrastructure. http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/

Answer (score 1):

[Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html) can provide callback functionality when using serial ports. It runs on Linux and Mac OS X.